# A question about a localization of a graded ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, graded-rings

Let $R=\oplus_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} R_i$ be a (commutative) graded ring of type $\mathbb{Z}$. It can be shown that if $S$ is a multiplicative set consists of homogeneous elements, $R_S$ have a natural grading structure of type $\mathbb{Z}$.

My question is:

> If $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ (possibly not homogeneous), then is it true that $(R_S, \mathfrak{p}R_S)$ is a local ring, where $S=\{F\in R \mid F$ is homogeneous and $F\not\in \mathfrak{p}\}$?

I know that the subring (of degree $0$) $R_{S,0} \subset R_S$  is local, and if a graded ring $A$ is local then the subring (of degree $0$) $A_0 \subset A$ is local, too.

Comment: Although $R_S$ is not local, it has many properties analogous to a local ring. See the  relevant chapter in Bruns and Herzog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Let $R=k[x]$ for $k$ a field and let $\mathfrak{p}=(x)$. Then there are no nonconstant homogeneous elements not in $(x)$, so $S=k^\times$ and $R_S=k[x]$ which is not local.

Comment: Yes you're right. This is also a counterexample, if we assume $\mathfrak{p}$ is homogeneous. Thanks.